# What is a dereferencable scalar in PHP?

Tags: php, object, methods

Recently, I was following [this PHP talk](https://talks.php.net/vienna17#/php7uvs) <sup>[See it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYTKm2oUzAg)</sup>. There is a part about new features in PHP7 that is a really strange stuff for me (in "Uniform variable syntax" part of the talk), which wrote:

```
// support all operations on dereferencable scalars
// (not very useful)
"string"->toLower()
```

[image: Uniform variable syntax part of the PHP talk image]

What is a dereferencable scalar? I know when I call a method on a non-object, for example:

```
echo "string"->toLower();
```

I'll get the following Error in PHP7:

```
Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toLower() on string
```

Also, I cannot find a way to declare methods on strings (like something we see in JavaScript); as I know, there is no way to do it.

So, what is the code above saying? How can we do the stuff above? What is the use case for it? Saying it generally, what is `"string"->toLower()`?

**(Editted) Note:** While the PHP talks says it *exists* as of PHP 7.0, it seems to be a mistake by Mr. Lerdorf (it could be a rejected patch, for example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " Also, I cannot find a way to declare methods on strings (like something we see in JavaScript)" You sure that is possible in Javascript because i can't remember thats possible or even encountered it.

Comment: That's two different things. Uniform variable syntax had the side effect of allowing `"strpos"(…)` to work. Scalars doubling as objects has not been implemented yet (or, had been rejected in earlier versions).

Comment: @RaymondNijland See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: Oh that is what you mean.. Strings in Javascript are extended from a Object, in PHP they are not, like @AlexShesterov already said in his answer.

Comment: @mario, please take a look at the PHP talk. It says **there is** something like this but it's not useful, and I asked "how to use it" or "I cannot use it".

Comment: @Subsurf Well you could can offcource make some kind off string class which makes it possible if you really want it.. Question is if you want to sacrifice RAM usage to make it possible http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a109f7fa1dfe6cc07d1143e6eac786d50317a1a  or if you really want to make it fun to chain methodes http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a72efa3ff6ab22b3fe2d7299a6d0a155dc42ce8

Comment: This feels like a rehash of yesterdays [reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/9f4bve/i_want_scalar_objects_in_php/?st=jm1zf7mb&sh=196c8822). And yes, there was a patch.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** this *would be* a syntax sugar.

**Longer answer:** This is a way to call functions with the syntax which aligns with the object syntax.

For example, an object (i.e. a class instance) could have a method called "length()". The invocation of this method would be expressed with the following "arrow" syntax:

```
$length = $myObject->length();
```

But, for example, to get a length of a string, you can't currently use the same syntax, because strings are not objects. Instead, you must put the variable name within the parentheses, as a parameter to the `strlen` function , i.e.:

```
$length = strlen($myString);
```

What you have mentioned is an *idea* to unify the syntax, i.e.

```
$length = $myString->strlen();
```

would be another possible *syntax* to call the `strlen` function. This would make operations on scalars (and arrays) *syntactically* closer to the objects' method calls.

*Note that PHP doesn't support this syntax yet, as of 2018-09-14.*

Comment: I had to google that feature because I had not yet seen anything like it in PHP. Took me a while to understand that it is actually not yet implemented, the linked slideshow made it look like it already is part of PHP7.

Comment: @Subsurf PHP was first designed to be procedural only instead of object oriented (OOP).. OOP was added in PHP since version 5 which was pretty late.. PHP was made around 1994 i believe PHP 5 was made around 2004 so PHP was more or less 10 years procedural only

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah I know, I've been working with PHP for almost 15 years now ;) That's why I was especially curious about that syntax